# Android device using "Shark for Root" to capture packets but receive "Empty file opened" error

Tags: android, wireshark, packet-capture

I'm using the "Shark for Root" to capture packets in my Android device. Here is the app in play store: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lv.n3o.shark

I just use the default parameters : `-vv -s 0` , and as the log shown below it really start to capture. But when I stop capture and open the capture file with the application named "Shark Reader", it exit with a toast that says "empty file opened" though the file isn't empty.

I can't find out what's wrong with it. Can some one help me or give me some advice to capture the packets.

Thanks.

Comment: Ever figure this out?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to add the input device like this
-vv -s 0 -i wlan0

wlan0 is your default wifi device name, if you want to capture other devices type netcfg in the command terminal to check the list of devices and their names